# Rails: Javascript for tracking sessions firing inconsistently

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, mixpanel

I have some JS code in my Rails app that fires a tracking event to Mixpanel on a new session.

Theoretically, before any other event is fired, I should see the "New Session" event first. But on some visits, I don't see the "New Session" event which means it's not being fired on some occasions.

What's wrong with the below code?

```
$(function(){
  var currentLocation = window.location.hostname;
  var lastLocation = document.referrer;
  if (lastLocation.indexOf(currentLocation) > -1) {
  } else {
    mixpanel.track("New Session", {});
  }
  mixpanel.track("Page View", {});
});
```

Comment: are you using turbolinks in your project?

Comment: also redirects. Imagine someone visits a locked page when they're logged out, the server redirects them to the login page. the referrer would be set to your domain, and the event wouldn't be fired

Comment: @BlairAnderson I think that's actually the problem. There's some http https redirects. Want to leave an answer?

Comment: @BlairAnderson although I'm testing it using a redirected page right now and the session is firing...

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Turbolinks the ready event is not fired after the first page load, so you need to bind to custom turbolinks events like `page:load` like:

```
var ready;
ready = function() {
  var currentLocation = window.location.hostname;
  var lastLocation = document.referrer;
  if (lastLocation.indexOf(currentLocation) > -1) {
  } else {
    mixpanel.track("New Session", {});
  }
  mixpanel.track("Page View", {});
};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

For **Rails 5** the event name changed to `turbolinks:load`

Answer (score 1):

You need to figure out how to reproduce the issue before you can really solve the problem.

We know the code is being ran, I'd recommend utilizing the if-statement for your tracking and adding data.

```
$(function(){
  var currentLocation = window.location.hostname;
  var lastLocation = document.referrer;
  if (lastLocation.indexOf(currentLocation) > -1) {
    // internal links
    mixpanel.track("Page View", {});
  } else {
    // external or non-existant link
    // bookmarks and email links won't have referrers
    mixpanel.track("New Session", {referrer: document.referrer});
    mixpanel.track("Page View", {});
  }
})
```